# Issue with using ex commands

Tags: command-line, cut-copy-paste, ex-mode

I asked a [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/370527/copy-a-block-of-text-to-a-specific-point-in-another-file) a few days ago in the Linux/Unix SE about how to copy a block of text from one file to another in a way that I could use for a script of many similar files. I thought I came up with a pretty simple solution, but I have run into a snag: my code seems to work only the first time I execute it. Any time after it won't seem to do. For an example, here is the gist of my code:

```
ex -c "normal! 1gg19|^V48gg59|y" -cq file1
```

This goes into file1, creates a visual block from the point (1,19) to (48,59) in the file, yanks it, and then closes the file.

```
ex -c "normal! 9gg21|p" -cwq file2
```

This goes into file2, moves the cursor to the point (9,21), pastes, and then closes the file.

If I run this once, it seems to work fine (minus any hiccups I cause by messing up the line numbers). But then if I run it again, neither line of code (in particular the first line) does anything. I have tried performing what each line of code is supposed to do in just plain vi, but then the other line will do nothing.

One particular issue I've noticed is if I run the first line and then try to manually perform the second, I get an error message "E353: Nothing in register"

Comment: When you give the code snippet, are you running that from a command line I.e. `vim ex -c"...` or are you running it from vim, `:ex -c "...` or is it in a vimrc `ex -c"...`?

Comment: @Tumbler41 I'm running these from the command line. The end goal was to incorporate them into a for loop.

Comment: Ok, the `ex` confused me for a bit, but I'm assuming that `ex` is just aliased to `vim` on your system? (That's standard for Linux machines these days right?)

Comment: @Tumbler41 yeah it just opens the file in ex mode.

Comment: Could not reproduce on Windows7 Vim 8.0.586. I asked some people to try it on Linux, but they haven't got back.

Comment: @Tumbler41 to clarify, it doesn't reproduce the error after reattempting or the code doesn't work as described?

Comment: It doesn't produce the error after reattempting the code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how your approach could work as it would mean the unnamed register is available between two separate 'ex' processes.

If you can do a single invocation this works:

```
ex -c 'normal! 1gg19|^V48gg59|y' -c 'edit file2' -c 'normal! 9gg21|p' -cwq file1
```

Note: I tried your way except putting it in the star (*) register thinking the clipboard would persist it across ex calls but that didn't work for me.

Comment: Vim saves away registers in the `.viminfo` file. So the unnamed register is actually saved between instances.

Comment: Before I answered I wondered if that was the case but when I tried it it did not work. The text does not get copied to the second file. For that matter it wasn't in my .viminfo file either. Thus I assumed it wasn't correct and answered with the single-command version. Maybe OP would be better off going that direction since at least two of us have issues with the two command approach. :)

Comment: @BlairM. I gave this method a try and ran into the same problem; it seems to run, but then there is no change to the file1.

Comment: Do you mean file2? BTW, I just noticed the `:wv` and `:rv` commands. Maybe these can be used with the two-command use case. Check out `:help viminfo-read-write`. (Sorry I'm in a hurry...can't try it out myself until later.)

Comment: @Tyberius `:wv/rv` make a lot of sense and I had high hopes to get the two-liner to work...but no luck. The register is just not read from viminfo with the second command so the put to file2 just complains about empty register. My one liner works great for me, though. Maybe you should focus on getting that to work. BTW, if you leave off the 'q' command you will still be in ex and you'll be able to easily read any. errors/messages, examine registers, etc.